# Run new zsh and bash shells with custom as command line agrument

Tags: bash, customization, command-prompt, zsh

Is it possible to run new `zsh` or `bash` shell with custom `PS1` set from command line? It should overwrite the default theme set by `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` respectively.

I'm talking about something like `zsh --myprompt="yes master? >"`

**EDIT:**
I do not want to affect any user-side configuration files. I want it to work for any user with any configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own "shim" rcfile that's available to your users then call that with the `--rcfile` option (for bash) or `--rcs` option (for zsh). This should source the user's rcfile first. For example, let's call this /usr/local/share/.fancypromptrc. In bash this might look like:

```
source "$HOME/.bashrc"
export PS1="DOLLAZ $"
```

And in zsh this might look like:

```
source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc"
export PS1="DOLLAZ $"
```

Then the user would start bash with `bash --rcfile /usr/local/share/.fancypromptrc`. In zsh it would be `zsh --rcs /usr/local/share/.fancypromptrc`.

This way the user doesn't have to modify their rcfile and if they are already setting PS1 it will still be replaced. The only time I can imagine this not working is if they have a PROMPT_COMMAND that overwrites the PS1, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you! This is simmilar to my answer. If I'm getting everything correctly, when executing shell with `--rcs` option, the shell does not load the user options first? In that case I would stick with my solution, but thank you for solving the problem! :) Additional I jsut tedted it on a example file and I do not know why, but the child shell is not using the file pointed by `--rcs`.

Comment: You'll still have to source the user's .bashrc/.zshrc from your shim rcfile, like in the example above. What version of zsh are you using?

Comment: The zsh version is 5.0.5 on my system.

Comment: Strange, I'm running 5.0.2 and it's working there. Maybe we can figure it out if you post a gist with the output of `zsh --version`, `zsh --rcs somefile` and the contents of `somefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do from the command line is likely to be overridden by your configuration files. You'll need to modify the appropriate file slightly to use something like

```
# *After* you make any changes to PS1
if [[ -n $MY_PS1 ]]; then
    PS1=$MY_PS1
fi
```

If you invoke the shell as

```
MY_PS1='yes master? > ' bash   # or zsh
```

then `MY_PS1` will be used instead of whatever is configured in `.{bash,zsh}rc`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it indeed should work, but I need a solution, which will work for **any** user, without affecting users config files - is it possible? I added this constrain to the question.

Comment: You could use `PS1='...' bash --norc --noprofile` to completely turn off any configuration file processing (`zsh` has similar options available), which will prevent any further modification of `PS1` beyond what you specify, but this may turn off a lot of other configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. We should just create a dir with custom config files, like `.zshrc`:

```
source $ZDOTDIR_ORIG/.zshrc
export PS1="[x] "$PS1
```

and then use a script to execute child shell remembering original value of `ZDOTDIR` var under `ZDOTDIR_ORIG` name, like this pseudopythoncode:

```
if os.environ.has_key('ZDOTDIR'):
    zdotdir = os.environ['ZDOTDIR']
else:
    zdotdir = os.path.expanduser('~')

os.environ["ZDOTDIR"] = shellConfPath
os.environ["ZDOTDIR_ORIG"] = zdotdir
```

And then execute the shell. It will use the config file from `ZDOTDIR` directory.

Answer (score -1):

wouldn't `export PS1='yes master? >' zsh/bash` work?

I see no reason why it shouldn't be as simple as that and yet achieve what you were after

Comment: Hmm, I do not know why, but it indeed works. I was executing the shell from Python setting the child environment using python's function but it get overriden. When trying this method it just works, without overriding by childs config, yay :)

Comment: This *does not* work. Drop the keyword `export`, and it might, if the user's configuration files do not change the value of `PS1`.

Comment: @chepner: Right! I was confused by the test in terminal. It does not work for child process. It just exports the value in current shell.